# GreaseMonkey countdown not working?

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm very confused, with greasemonkey setTimeout just isn't working, it never calls the function, looking online people say greasemonkey doesn't support setTimeout, is there anyway to make my objective (below) work?

```
function countdown(time, id) {
   if(document.getElementById(id)) {
       var name = document.getElementById(id);
       var hrs = Math.floor(time / 3600); 
       var minutes = Math.floor((time - (hrs * 3600)) / 60); 
       var seconds = Math.floor(time - (hrs * 3600) - minutes * 60);

       if(hrs>0) {
            name.innerhtml = hrs + 'h ' + minutes + 'm';
       } else if(minutes>0) {
            name.innerhtml = minutes + 'm ' + seconds + 's';
       } else {
            name.innerhtml = seconds + 's';
       }
   } else {
       setTimeout('countdown(' + --time + ',' + id + ')', 100);
   }

   if(time <= 0)
      window.location.reload();
   else
      setTimeout('countdown(' + --time + ',' + id + ')', 1000);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem lies in the textual parameter of `setTimeout`. It works very well with greasemonkey but if you use textual commands instead of callbacks, the code is never executed since greasemonkey sandbox is cleared by the time the `setTimeout` fires. It tries to run `eval` with the textual parameter wchis in turn tries to call function `countdown` which doesn't exist by that time anymore.

Currently the program flow is as follows:

```
1. function countdown(){}

2. setTimeout("countdown()", 1000);

3. clearGreasemonkeySandbox();

4. ... wait 1 sec...

5. eval("countdown()"); // <- countdown doesn't exist anymore
```

So you should use callbacks instead, this way a pointer to a function is used instead of the full sentence.

```
setTimeout(function(){
    countdown(--time, id);
}, 1000);
```

Comment: This is mostly right, except when you use a string instead of a callback the string is made in to a function and called in the window scope which is why the userscript functions are not found. Also the userscript's sandbox scope isn't cleared until the user leaves the page, which is when it is deleted.

Answer (score 1):

In the end I ended up using

```
window.setTimeout(bla, 1000);
```

and

`window.bla = function() { alert("cool"); }`

Comment: This works because of what Amdris said (with my corrections).