# java script for grease monkey loop

Tags: javascript, loops, greasemonkey

what i need is a for or while loop that will re run the code every second
ive tried sleep() but i dont think it is working or i have got it right

Answer (score 4):

Do not try to use a `for` or `while` loop for such timed operations.  You'll have a hard time with reliable or accurate timing and usually end up railing the CPU, making the computer sluggish.

JavaScript provides the `setInterval()` function for these kinds of tasks.  Also note that [Greasemonkey has some caveats about how to use `setInterval()` and `setTimeout()`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3131026/greasemonkey-countdown-not-working/3131717#3131717).

So the code you want is like:

```
var timerVar    = setInterval (function() {DoMeEverySecond (); }, 1000);

function DoMeEverySecond ()
{
    //--- Your code here.
}

//--- When ready to stop the timer, run this code:
clearInterval (timerVar);
timerVar        = "";
```

Comment: +1 brock, good point re my setTimeout. i did of course mean setInterval (also, very good point re parameters!!). fingers faster than brain!! seasons greetings... :-)

Answer (score 1):

try

```
// where yourfunction is a method that contains your loop logic
setTimeout(yourfunction, 1000);
```

This will invoke the function every 1000 milliseconds without having to embed it into a while or for loop.

put it into your body onload or similar event

Comment: This should be `setInterval`, not `setTimeout`.  Also, it's a good idea to show the anonymous function syntax, in case the function requires parameters.